# Listview - Opening a new activity with OnItemClickListener

Tags: android, listview, android-activity, onitemclicklistener

I have a listview and I am trying to receive “click” events when the user selects an item in the list using the OnItemClickListener. What is supposed to happen is when a list item is clicked it should open a new activity however, every time I run the application and try to click on any of the list items nothing happens. I've been trying to figure out what could be wrong with my code but haven't found a solution yet and would like any suggestions.

This is my Mainactivity code:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //linking of variable to the UI for list view element with id
    newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsFeedList);
    //create adapter
    adapter = new NewsListAdapter (this, R.layout.adapter_news_list, newsListData);
    //attach adapter to list view
    newsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
    EDANewsApp app = EDANewsApp.getInstance();
    //URL that we want to communicate with
    String url = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getList.php";
    //Attach on item click listener to list view
    newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(listListener);
    //Create a request(we expect a JSON array as a response
    JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, listener, errorListener);
    //Submit the request
    app.requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);
}
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Create an Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsItemActivity.class);
        NewsRecord record = new NewsRecord();
        //Add parameters
        intent.putExtra("NEWS_ITEM_ID", record.recordId);
        //Retrieve record object for selected news item
        newsListData.get(position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You arent starting new Activity.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsItemActivity.class);
```

After creation of an intent you have to call

```
startActivity(intent)
```

From an Activity. In your code that would be MainActivity.
Please also check if NewsItemActivity is added in to Manifest file as activity

Comment: thank you I had added the startActivity(intent) but still no new activity is appearing!

Comment: Please also check if NewsItemActivity is added in to Manifest file as activity

Comment: Does any log appear in logcat?

Comment: Oh...it works now. I changed the position of the newsListData.get(position) and placed it above the intent :$

Answer (score 0):

Like Adam points out, you are missing:

```
startActivity(intent)
```

So your code must looks like:

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        //Create an Intent
        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsItemActivity.class);
        NewsRecord record = new NewsRecord();
        //Add parameters
        intent.putExtra("NEWS_ITEM_ID", record.recordId);
        //Retrieve record object for selected news item
        newsListData.get(position);
       startActivity(intent)
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

@Janet Rodriguez:
I got your problem. Your are missing out of the adapter.
see:

```
adapter = new NewsListAdapter (this, R.layout.adapter_news_list, newsListData);
```

Here you are setting a custom adapter.

but Here :

```
AdapterView.OnItemClickListener listListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {});
```

And here you are getting onitemclicklistener of a different adapter that is never used in your list view.
At Last solution:
you can directly call this method from listview.
Like:

```
newsListView .setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsItemActivity.class);
    NewsRecord record = new NewsRecord();
    //Add parameters
    intent.putExtra("NEWS_ITEM_ID", record.recordId);
    //Retrieve record object for selected news item
    newsListData.get(position);
   startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

Try this and reply if more problem:

Answer (score 0):

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
//linking of variable to the UI for list view element with id
 newsListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.newsFeedList);
//create adapter
 adapter = new NewsListAdapter (this, R.layout.adapter_news_list, newsListData);
//attach adapter to list view
newsListView.setAdapter(adapter);
EDANewsApp app = EDANewsApp.getInstance();
//URL that we want to communicate with
String url = "http://www.efstratiou.info/projects/newsfeed/getList.php";
//Attach on item click listener to list view
newsListView.setOnItemClickListener(listListener);
//Create a request(we expect a JSON array as a response
JsonArrayRequest jsonRequest = new JsonArrayRequest(url, listener, errorListener);
//Submit the request
app.requestQueue.add(jsonRequest);

// List View Listener

list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, NewsItemActivity.class);
    NewsRecord record = new NewsRecord();
    //Add parameters
    intent.putExtra("NEWS_ITEM_ID", record.recordId);
    //Retrieve record object for selected news item
    newsListData.get(position);
    startActivity(intent);          
            }
        });

}
```

Replace this code in to your oncreate and please remove adapterview on click listener this will sure help you if not than let me know i will find you out another perfect solutions